IsaacGym for Non-Physics RL tasks
Basically, I want to set up an environment that involves training a model, so the environment has to be loaded to the GPU for a conventional RL task and not robotics. Is IsaacGym the right tool?
Seems all the examples I saw are physics simulation based environment.
